# DocuSign - How to add ClientUserId to an existing envelope signer

Tags: docusignapi

I have list of envelopes and signer created in DocuSign. I forgot to add unique ClientUserId while creating the envelope. The Unique ClientUserId is needed to do [Embedded Signing](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-in-app-embedded/) in the app.

How can I add the ClientUserId to a signer for an existing DocuSign envelope?

Answer (score 0):

If the envelope was already sent, then the signer would get an email. You can correct the envelope, but you can't unring a bell sort of speak.

If the envelope is in draft, you can still update it. You can use a PUT method for the envelope recipients to modify the reicipients.

Comment: My envelopes are already sent. So I see there is no option to update the existing envelope signer (clientuserid) to enable the embedding option. Thank you.

Comment: You could still update it using a PUT call and add the clientUserId, but the email to that user already was sent.

Comment: @InbarGazit is there a way for us to remove clientUserId from recipients?
I have sent an envelope with clientUserId and now I want to resend the signing email to the user, but because clientUserId is present, they aren't getting an email, and I tried update recipients endpoint, but unable to remove clientUserId

Comment: You will need to correct the envelope by locking it first, and then modifying the recipients, you may even need to remove and re-add the recipient you want, not 100% sure about that part, but I know for sure you need to use correct

Comment: https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/common-api-tasks-correct-envelope-your-app

Comment: This blog shows the locking/unlocking and then the correct view, you don't need to do the correct view, but then you do need to lock, update recipients, unlock